# Replicate Postman Oauth 2.0 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0

I have this Authorization request that works.

How can I replicate it in Python?

I am using an Azure AD to authenticate the access.

[image: Token Request]

Comment: A web is launched when you press the "Generate Access" button?  Are you working for a web with human login (interactive) or Does your app (non interactive) need an access token to perform some operation in azure?

Comment: @JRichardsz, I would be okay if my Python would open a web page for human login.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with python, your case is a : Oauth2 login for SSR web applications with Microsoft

### Goal

Get an access_token from interactive login using the oauth2 authorization code grant

[image]

### Steps

Here I will list all the steps required to do it with any language

- Create a web with session with at least these endpoints

  - `/` : home page
  - `/callback` : server route or path able to receive query params like `/callback?code=123456`. This along with your base domain  will be called **redirect_uri**. Sample : http://localhost:8080/callback or http://acme.com/callback
- Create and configure an app in Azure Dev Console. Same process is in Google, Facebook, Linkedin, etc. As a result you should have a clientId, clientSecret and a redirect url
- Create a simple web with classic session in which if user is not logged-in, redirect (302) to this url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=foo&response_type=code&redirect_uri=foo&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read
```

- clientid and redirect_uri are important here and should be the same of previous step
- After that, browser should redirect the user to the platform login

  [image]
- If user enters valid credentials and accepts the consent warning, Microsoft will perform another redirect (302) to the provided redirect_uri but with special value: **The auth code**

  ```
  http://acme.com/callback?code=123456798
  ```
- In the backend of /callback get the code and send it to this new endpoint

  1. Add a `client_id` & `client_secret` parameters
  2. Add a `code` parameter with the **code** sent by microsoft
  3. Add a `redirect_uri` parameter with previously used and registered on azure. Sample `http://acme.com/callback` or `http://localhost:8080/callback`
  4. Add a `grant_type` parameter with a value of `authorization_code`
  5. Issue the HTTP POST request with content-type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- You should get a response with the precious **access_token**:

```
{
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  scope: 'Mail.Read User.Read profile openid email',
  expires_in: 5020,
  ext_expires_in: 5020,
  access_token: 'eyJ0oVlKhZHsvMhRydQ',
  refresh_token: 's_Rcrqf6xMaWcPHJxRFwCQFkL_qUYqBLM71UN6'
}
```

- You could do with this token, whatever you configured in azure. Sample: If you want to access to user **calendar, profile, etc** on behalf of the user, you should have registered this in the azure console. So the clientid is related to that and human user will be prompted with something like this

  [image]

### Libraries

There is some libraries provided by microsoft (c#, nodejs) which will save you a little work. Anyway the previous explanation are very detailed.

### Advice

- Read about oauth2 spec: https://oauth.net/2/
- Read about **oauth2 authorization code flow** login before the implementation with python

  - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2
  - https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow
  - https://github.com/msusdev/microsoft_identity_platform_dev/blob/main/presentations/auth_users_msalnet.md
- Check this to understand how configure the azure web console: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app
- Check my gist https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/5b8ba730978fce7a7c585007d3fd06b4

Comment: Thank you @JRichardsz!

Here is the thing. I don't have access to the API (at least not during the weekend).

When I fetch the token from Postman, the API accepts redirect_uri = 'https://postman"; however, when I write it on Python, the API does not accept redirect_uri = 'https://localhost' (or any other combinations I tried to guess.

Is there a way my Python can intercept the https://postman callback (that I do know that works)?

Comment: What do you mean by api? Azure accepts localhost but with port